# Regex not matching fr or en

Tags: python, regex, django

I need a regex to match patterns like:

> /page/my-slug/
>   /a-langage-acronyme/page/my-slug/

and to not match patterns like:

> /fr/page/my-slug/
>   /en/page/my-slug/

I tried:

```
r'^(?!(fr/|en/))page/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/'
```

But it doesn't even match:

> /de/page/my-slug/

Comment: You should note that lookaheads don't match anything, they just check. So if you remove that part for a moment, you are matching a pattern of `^page/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/`. Seems to me you need something along the lines of `^/(?!(?:fr|en)/)(?:\w+/)?page/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/`

Comment: It doesn't match as it is but, if I take off the `?!` it does match the opposite of what I'm looking for ...

Comment: Well that's the difference between a capturing group and a lookahead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^/(?!fr|en)\w{2}/page/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/

^                ## the start of the string
/               ## matches "/" character
(?!fr|en)        ## should not match "fr" or "en"
\w{2}            ## needs 2 words characters e.g. "de"
/page/         ## matches "/page/"
(?P<slug>[\w-]+) ## named capture group "slug" : matches one or more word and "-" characters
/               ## matches "/" character
```

> https://regex101.com/r/ZXiNCO/2

**Update**

```
^(?:/(?!fr|en)[\w-]+)?/page/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/
```

> https://regex101.com/r/ZXiNCO/4

Matching :

```
/page/my-slug/
/de/page/my-slug/
/de_DE/page/my-slug/
/de-BE/page/my-slug/
/deLU/page/my-slug/
```

Not matching :

```
/en/page/my-slug/
/enUS/page/my-slug/
/en_US/page/my-slug/
/en-US/page/my-slug/
/enUS/page/my-slug/
/fr/page/my-slug/
/fr_FR/page/my-slug/
```

Comment: This doesn't match `/page/my-slug/` which is stated as sample to match in OP. It also assumes that language acronyms are always 2 characters - which in itself seems fine, but should be stated. You should also add some explanation to your code.

Comment: I haven't paid attention to that. You are right. I'm about to edit the regex

Comment: As sebastian said it doesn't match /page/slug/ but is the closest answer. I'll just do 2 regex, one will be yours.

Comment: @user2021091 I've updated my answer. Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Yes this is great !

Answer (score 0):

I would personally take a slightly different approach:

```
import re

regex = "^/(?:fr|de)/"

mylist = [
"/fr/a-langage-acronyme/page/my-slug/",
"/en/a-langage-acronyme/page/my-slug/",
]

for text in mylist:
    if not re.search(regex, text):
        print ("do stuff with " + text)
    else:
        print ("those silly fr and de, nein!")
```

You can make a pretty good regex to do what you want, but if you really just want to avoid paths that start with something specific, look for those and don't use them.  Just another way to look at it.  Sometimes easy readability will save you down the road :)

Comment: I wish I could not use regex but I don't have the choice  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#example